# How can I get untouched status change when click enter in a inputbox

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-lifecycle-hooks, change-detector-ref

Here is simple input box in a reactive form:
Html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type="text" formControlName="box" (keyup.enter)="dosomething()">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

TS:

```
  dosomething() {
    this.cd.detectChanges(); // private *cd*: ChangeDetectorRef
    console.log(this.form.untouched);
  } 
  onSubmit() {
    console.log('from submit: ', this.form.untouched);
  }
```

input something in the input box

-> click enter, I got: ***true***;

-> click the submit button, I got: ***false***

In this case, cz the input box has already been touched, so, we should expect the ***false***.

How can I get the ***false*** when clicking enter in the input box?

[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8j3dvg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: this.form.markAllAsTouched() should do the trick

Comment: @GerardoGonzalez Thanks, it's worded, but seems we manually change the form statues as touched. Don't know if it's the only solution for it~

Comment: form.untouched is updated when the focus moves on to next element. So when you press enter key the focus is still on the input element so form does not update the untouched value so it stays **true** when you click enter button and when you press the submit button the focus moves on to the submit button so form fields gets updated and untouched value becomes **false**.